# Changing the size of sub- and superscripts for the whole document

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I want to change the sizes of sub- and superscripts of formulas as their font size is already set to `\scriptsize`. Is there a way to decrease the font size of all formulas written in `\scriptsize` by predefining the size in the preamble?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to change the size of script style material, shouldn't you also change the size of scriptscript style material?

Comment: Untested: `\let\scriptsize\tiny` ??? But the size of `\scriptsize` is small already

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: In what sense did it not work?

Comment: @JPi It didn't do nothing at all.

Comment: You can change the math sizes with `\DeclareMathSizes`, but \scriptsize is already very small, and I doubt that smaller subscripts are readable -- I at least wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: The math script size is defined as being a fraction: `\def\defaultscriptratio{.7}` within `latex.ltx`. You can redefine it and use `\calculate@math@sizes` afterwards, but if there's no font supporting that size you're out of luck

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How exactly would that look like written out?

Comment: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\defaultscriptratio}{.5}
\renewcommand{\defaultscriptscriptratio}{.3}
\calculate@math@sizes
\makeatother` -- but I don't recommend it at all